# How do I use removeMarker in GMaps.js to filter markers?

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps

I'm using GMaps.js. I've added markers with JSON, and would like to filter (hide) some markers based on values in that JSON. Ie, hide all markers which don't have a value `foo` for property `bar`.

I'm able to use [`map.removeMarkers()`](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/documentation.html#GMaps-removeMarkers), it just removes all markers, and I see in my console there is another method called `removeMarker()`, but I don't know how I'd specify a particular marker.

I know it's not the same library, but the documentation has been useful before, so I've been taking tips from the [jQuery maps filtering documentation](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_sample_code#Example_filter_tags,_categories,_etc_with_find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the  `map.removeMarker()` method you need to keep track of your markers. and pass the marker you want to remove to the method.
Other than that you can use `map.map` which returns the map object from google maps api, and you can use the google maps api methods.